# shift +click functionality on listbox item using WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, listbox

I need to add functionality on List box Item where the user can select the item by clicking each item individually and can also do shift+click to select a series of items in the list.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemFields, Mode=TwoWay}"
         VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
         Margin="16,156,0,34" Name="fRListbox" Width="499" >                   
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>                            
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
            <EventSetter Event="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" Handler="reportDatagrid_MouseDown"/>                              
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

and on xaml.cs I wrote below code:

```
private void ListItem_MouseClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    if ((e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
    {
        fRListbox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Extended;
    }
    else if ((e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed) && Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift))
    {
        fRListbox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
    }
    else if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        fRListbox.SelectionMode = SelectionMode.Multiple;
    }
}
```

But Shift +Click functionality is not working.
I am new to WPF can anyone guide me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're happy for users to select items by holding the `Ctrl` key down when clicking individual items (like Windows Explorer and pretty much every other type of list) then setting `SelectionMode` to `Extended` is the simplest way to achieve single and multiple selections using the `Ctrl` and `Shift` keys.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ValuesView}" SelectionMode="Extended" />
```

Comment: Ya I have already tried this but this does not serve the purpose of selecting the item by clicking each item individually.I need both the selection mode .Pls help.

Comment: Give your users the UI they expect, not the UI you think they should have. All users learn early to use the Ctrl key when selecting non-contiguous items in a list - if you make your list do something different, they'll hate your app for forcing them to work differently from every other app.

Comment: I need both the functionality as previously selectionmode was "multiple" which was doing the click selection of invidual item but the requirement from user end is to have shift+click as well so that this can ease up the series selection of item.

Comment: @MarkGreen Allowing multi-select without holding down Ctrl is perfectly reasonable depending on the use case. WPF does provide `SelectionMode.Multiple` for that purpose, after all. The problem here is that `SelectionMode.Multiple` disables the ability to use Shift+Click to select consecutive items or Ctrl+A to select all, which seems to be a bug/oversight.