# Add shift modifier to WPF ListBox in Multiple mode?

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

There are 3 modes for the *WPF* `ListBox`:

- Multiple
- Extended
- Single

I'd like the `ListBox` to exhibit behavior from both *Multiple* and *Extended* modes however.  So, I'd like the behavior of *Multiple* with the toggling selection, however also want to be able to use the *SHIFT* key for selecting a range.

What would be the best way to achieve that?  Do I need to investigate the drag drop framework for this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [shift +click functionality on listbox item using WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22354509/shift-click-functionality-on-listbox-item-using-wpf)

Comment: looks like a similar requirement yes, but the responses aren't great.

Comment: Your explanation is not very clear. Do you want users to single click items without holding ctrl to select multiple, and if they hold shift it will select everything between one click and the next?

Comment: Yes - basically allow (at least) the Shift functionality to work in Multiple mode.  By default you cannot use modifiers (like Shift and CTRL) in Multiple mode.

Answer (score 0):

I added code to support this in the mouse event handlers.

private int _firstIndex = -1;

```
    private void UxDictionaryList_OnPreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var listbox = sender as ListBox;
        var source = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;

        while (source is ContentElement)
            source = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(source);

        while (source != null && !(source is ListBoxItem))
            source = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);

        var lbi = source as ListBoxItem;

        if (lbi != null && listbox != null && _firstIndex == -1)
        {
            bool isShiftPressed = Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) || Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift);

            //if (!isShiftPressed)
            //    _firstIndex = -1;
            //else
            //{
                int index = listbox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(lbi);
                _firstIndex = index;
            //}
        }
    }

    private void UxDictionaryList_OnMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void UxDictionaryList_OnPreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var listbox = sender as ListBox;
        var source = e.OriginalSource as DependencyObject;

        while (source is ContentElement)
            source = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(source);

        while (source != null && !(source is ListBoxItem))
            source = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(source);

        var lbi = source as ListBoxItem;

        if (lbi != null && listbox != null && _firstIndex > -1)
        {
            if (!lbi.IsSelected)
            {
                _firstIndex = -1;
                return;
            }

            if (Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.LeftShift) ||
                Keyboard.IsKeyDown(Key.RightShift))
            {
                int index = listbox.ItemContainerGenerator.IndexFromContainer(lbi);

                if (index > _firstIndex)
                {
                    for (var i = _firstIndex; i <= index; i++)
                    {
                        ListBoxItem lbItem = (ListBoxItem)listbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                        lbItem.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (index < _firstIndex)
                {
                    for (var i = _firstIndex; i >= index; i--)
                    {
                        ListBoxItem lbItem = (ListBoxItem)listbox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(i);
                        lbItem.IsSelected = true;
                    }
                }

                // Reset first selected index
                _firstIndex = -1;
            }
        }
    }
```